# Does the typeof operator continuously show different data types assigned that changed for one variable?

Tags: javascript, types, operators, literals

I'm currently fiddling around with the typeof operator for the variables I'm declaring. What I did in chrome developer was create a statement that declared multiple variables just like this.

```
var x, y, z;
```

Then, I decided to assign each variable in the statement like this.

```
var x = 7;
var y = 100;
var z = x + y;
```

Of course this is an arithmetic expression so the whole thing with each variable, once using a typeof operator, shows a string that says number.

Now I decided to just goof around to show quirks of Javascript and caught this.

I decided to just change each variable to undefined like this.

```
var x;
```

when I did this, I decided to use the typeof operator. What came out was just something that threw me off to the t'.

```
typeof (x);
```

The string was still returned as number.

My question is this, what's going on specifically in the example above that keeps showing me a datatype of number from the typeof operator when it's actually undefined?

Comment: `typeof` works on value, not on variables.

Comment: 'var x = 7', then declaring 'var x;' doesn't make 'x' undefined nor string. Use 'x = undefined', to make it so.

Comment: If you were doing these experiments in the console, they are executed in the same scope, and `var x` re-declares the variable instead of creating a new one. It did keep its value - try to log it.

Comment: I could be wrong, but isn't this just [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)? The `var` declarations are hoisted to the top, so essentially can be thought of as happening *before* the value assignment, hence it retains its value when interrogated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x=7;
var x;
```

That does not redeclare the variable. Variables cannot really be redeclared.
If you want to change your variable to undefined, do that:

```
var x=6;
x=undefined;
alert(typeof x);
```

Or you might want to delete it:

```
var context={x:6};
delete context.x;
alert(typeof context.x);
```

However, that does not work in the highest ( window ) scope.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you say;

> I decided to just change each variable to undefined like this.
>
> ```
> var x;
> ```

However, this is actually not setting `x` to undefined, for most practical purposes it's not really doing anything at all.

`x` will still evaluate to the value you previously assigned it (`7`).

If you set `x` to undefined (`x = undefined`), then the typeof will properly reflect it's new type (`typeof x` = `"undefined"`).

Answer (score 0):

The variables are created only once, so in the next they are only reused.

```
var x = 1;
...
x = 2;
...
x = undefined;
```

If you create the same variable twice, The computer will read the variable that has data.

```
var x = 1;
var x = 2;//this
...
var y = 1;//this
var y;
```